# Is it a sin to make jokes about being a priest?

Tags: catholicism, sin, priesthood, female-clergy

Sometimes my friends call me Father as a joke. It is funny because I am a woman and not a priest. We are wondering if this is a sin of irreverence.

Comment: Context matters. Reflect on it and discern whether the act is separating you from God in some way. Consult a priest for guidance, and provide them with the context.

Comment: It doesn't sound funny at all to me. It is probably better to focus on what it means to be a woman rather than what it does not mean to be a woman.  I think jokes and jargon can be difficult to interpret so ask someone who knows about your particular situation.

Answer (score 2):

I think you will find that humour in general is not a sin. You will also find that God has a certain sense of humour Himself. A few saints are known for making jokes. So, as a general rule, joking is not a sin.

But as said, context matters.

Answer (score 1):

This is a subjective matter.

I really think that a good joke can lift the spirit. I do not imagine the apostles living without joking. I imagine them living happily.

A joke can certainly be offensive, but **there are other jokes that simply reflect an unsuspected result from a small story**.

This is a question tagged with catholicism, so: I know many priests, and sometimes they joke about themselves, and no irreverence is implied or even considered, just a funny outcome.

The specific statement would hardly be a sin, but if you feel guilty, as a Catholic, just add it to your confession and be done.

Probably the other person can say that because of some kind of compliment, probably you gave a piece of good advice, probably a little critique if you are "preachy".

The definition of sin [Cathecism Number 1849](https://www.vatican.va/archive/ENG0015/__P6A.HTM)

> Sin is an offense against reason, truth, and right conscience; it is failure in genuine love for God and neighbor caused by a perverse attachment to certain goods. It wounds the nature of man and injures human solidarity. It has been defined as "an utterance, a deed, or a desire contrary to the eternal law.

Answer (score -3):

I think it's the same way the generation of Noah made fun of him while he was building the ark and the floods came and took them all away. It is a sin to make fun of a servant of God because God does not joke, **42 children made fun of Elisha the servant of God and he cursed them and a bear ate them all.**

The Pharisees and the high priest made fun of Jesus while he was on the cross and darkness covered the whole land from noon to the third hour in the afternoon, a great earthquake hit the city and the curtain of the temple was torn into two.

Comment: God doesn't joke?? God makes plenty of jokes in the Bible. Where would our capacity for humour even come from if not God?

Comment: @curiousdannii, yes God is ever serious and if you read the Bible carefully then when God speaks, lightning and thunders follow. Like when he said he has glorified the son and will glorify him again. Those who stood there said the voice had thundered. Now how does God whom when he speaks lighting and thunders follow make jokes?

Comment: @curiousdannii, your name is curious so you believe because you are curious. God never laughs or show me in the Bible where any member of the Holy Trinity made a joke or laughed. You should take your faith more seriously.

Comment: @curiousdannii, continue making jokes when the devil and his angels are serious about bringing the antichrist to the world stage and the mark of the beast, you think it's a joke for the Son of Man to get nailed on the foot and hands for the sins of the whole world? You think the devil jokes when he kills the saints for rejecting his mark?  God is serious about the number of the gentiles being filled so the end comes and so is the devil serious to make sure billions of men are condemned. There is no room for jokes in spiritual warfare.

Comment: @FewAgainstMany-Israel "He who sits in the heavens laughs"

Comment: That's just an expression. God is not a joker. Thunders and lightnings are for all creation to tremble before his presence. He doesn't joke and is a respect of no persons